# How do I put my Electron app in production mode

Tags: electron-builder, electron-packager

I have tried both builder and packager, after building the top menu is available which allows access to developer tools..how do I get rid of it?

Comment: if you don't want the menu you have to setup your browserWindow to disable it for ex: mainWindow.setMenu(null); But you still have to detect if you are in prod or in test.Personnally I have a config.ini where I put information to open Devtools or not and don't use the menu but only doing mainWindow.openDevTools(); when my config.ini tell me to do it?.

Answer (score 5):

If I've understood well you want to get rid of DevTools and the Menu bar

To disable DevTools you have to add `webPreferences.devTools = false` to all your Windows as shown here:

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    // Your window configuration

    webPreferences: {
        devTools: false // This will disable dev tools
    }
});
```

If you do this even by going to `Menu > View > Toggle Developer Tools` the DevTools panel won't show up

And to get rid of the Menubar:

```js
app.dock.hide(); // Only mac
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false); // Only Windows and Linux
// Or you can also use mainWindow.setMenu(null); on Windows and Linux
```

Everything on the main process